# Send data from BroadCastReceiver to running Service (Android)

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

How can I send some data from BroadCastReceiver to running service?
I tried using peekService but seem that method return null until service is binded from someone. Anyway if I bind service, I don't need to peek service and I can't bind service from BroadCastReceiver (I don't need any Activity)

My situation is:
my_broadcastreceiver -> start service
my_broadcastreceiver -> stop service
my_broadcastreceiver -> inform service of something (if service is already running, else nothing)

How can I do that?
Obviously I can write a BroadCastReceiver in service using a intent filter, but I think is not better way. I just want to send some information when BroadCastReceiver enter in onReceive method. I hope there is some possibility...

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Pack the data into an `Intent` and send it to the service with `startService()`. See  [putExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: Additionally, if service is not running, I don't wont start it!

Comment: I am interested in this also. If someone has a solution, please share.

Comment: @user1417608, " If this service is not already running, it will be instantiated and started (creating a process for it if needed); if it is running then it remains running." From Android manual.